# Open subset in Irreducible Topological Space is dense.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Show that every non-empty open subset of an irreducible topological space is dense.

I know a lemma that states that $U \subset$X is dense iff for all $A \in \tau$, $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

So then let U be an open set in $(X, \tau_{zar})$ that is irreducible. Then I want to show that for all $A \in \tau$, $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$. I don't know how to show this though, nor how the irreducibility fits in.

Comment: You mean "... iff for all $A\in \tau$ with $A\ne\emptyset$, $A\cap U\ne \emptyset$" (and in fact this is hardly a lemma, but a possible definition of *dense*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An open subset of an irreducible set is dense.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460074/an-open-subset-of-an-irreducible-set-is-dense)

Answer (score 5):

Let $U$ be a nonempty open subset of an irreducible topological space $X$. Denote by $\overline{U}$ the closure of $U$ in $X$. Then $(X - U, \overline{U})$ is a decomposition of $X$. Because $X$ is irreducible, one of these sets equals $X$. Since $U$ is nonempty,we have $$X \setminus U \neq X \implies \overline{U} = X.$$

Comment: Should it be $X\setminus U\neq X$?

Comment: Is it enough to say if $\bar U \ne X$, then $X = \bar U \cup X\setminus U$. So, $X$ is not reducible?

Answer (score 3):

Just show that every two open nonempty subsets intersect.

If not, take complements to show the space is reducible.

Comment: "every two open nonempty subsets intersect" is a possible definition of *irreducible topological space*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well he didn't state his definition, so I assumed it's "cannot be union of 2 proper closed subsets". Why would he ask this question if he had your definition?

Comment: Acknowledged. Then again, every "good" definition should start with a theorem "The following properties are equivalent" (e.g. not union opf proper closed subsets; any two nonempty open sets intersect, any nonempty open subset is dense) to motivate a subsequent definition "We call something ... if it has one (and hence all) of the above properties". Thus in a "good" exposition, the exercise should be void to begin with ...